# Get short path with '~' on windows when using java

Tags: java, windows, cmd, process, printwriter

I have created a java application which downloads files from an online source to my local computer which runs windows 7

The code downloads the file but also creates a path for that file so it can be stored in that path

The file then gets converted to another format

The issue that I am having is that it seems that windows don't like it if I navigate to the path using an absolute long path

I am using cmd to navigate to the file which means I am creating processes to do that

My code looks like this

```
 String[] command =
        {
                "cmd",
        };
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();

            PrintWriter stdOut = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(), true);
            stdOut.println("cd "+strPath);
```

As you can see above, the last line is just navigating to the path 
it works for most cases but not when the path is long and has '-' and other characters.

If I am on windows explorer and I click on the path at the navigation bar the path shows but with '~' if I embed the '~' path within this code by setting strPath to the path with the '~' everything works fine

Also if I take the absolute full path from strPath (by printing it to the screen for example) and I open cmd.exe then run the following command

```
cd <some absolute full path>   <- this works but doesn't work from java
```

So I am not sure what I need to do to fix it

Comment: What error message does the command shell return?

Comment: i do not get any errors , i follow that code with a simple command to convert the the file which is included in that path to docx using pandoc
String com = "pandoc -s -o \""+output+"\" \""+strBlogName+"\"";
   stdOut.println(com);

   stdOut.close();

after closing the stdout , i get an error says that the file doesnt exist ( the source file) which is not true cause it does exist

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there, but as Elliott has already pointed out, you should really be running `pandoc` directly via a `ProcessBuilder` rather than messing about with a child command shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (and you don't) use `~` for the home folder (that is a shell expansion). You can use `System.getProperty("user.home")` - which will return the home folder.

Comment: after returning the home folder , what do i do to navigate to the path that i want to navigate to? how can i get to that full path ?

Comment: [`ProcessBuilder.directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) and use `ProcessBuilder` (not `Runtime.exec`).

Comment: i am trying to use process builder but how do i run a command on cmd?

my code currently looks like this

File folder = new File(strPath);
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
  pb.directory(folder);
  

  Process p = null;
  try {
   //p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   p = pb.start();
   
   new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
   
   PrintWriter stdOut = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(), true);

   String com = "pandoc -s -o \""+output+"\" \""+strBlogName+"\"";
   stdOut.println(com);

   stdOut.close();

Comment: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pandoc", "-s", "-o", output+File.pathSeparator+strBlogName).directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));` And you might prefer to use [`pb.inheritIO();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) over manually reading the output.

Comment: this kind of worked but alot of files are still unreachable , if i take the same command and i run it using cmd.exe , i am getting a path or extension is too long (on windows)